# Very Sr. Mainframe Programmer, now w. 5 yrs Java/Spring,...how to market myself?

Tags: transition

I've been straddling Mainframe and Java Stack for 5 years now (with 25 years experience in mainframe before that), but the Java side has been self-learning pretty well in a vacuum (3 people training themselves while the company's true senior Java resources forbidden to assist us).  Now I am interested in working on Java in a more "normal" (meaning supported as a "real" or "regular" Java dev) environment.  We have successfully delivered Java/Spring apps using Maven/Eclipse and Dojo/JQuery on the front end.  I grok and employ the more esoteric OOP concepts (Patterns/IoC/Reflection/Object-Relational-Impedance-Mismatch), and I feel on solid ground working in a true Enterprise level environment.  BUT...I'm missing things like robust JUnit design, Agile development, Jenkins and nightly builds.

So, I am reluctant to bill myself as Sr. Java dev because I'm not going to be able *code* like a superstar out of the gate.  It's a bit of a scavenger hunt.

On the other hand, I am truly an Enterprise level full stack developer on the MF, side.  I can function as a DA with RDBMses, coding stored procedures, all the way through to screen design.  Plus some light Project Lead experience.  And surely this has transferable skills toward the Java Stack environment.

How best condense all the above into a quick log-line for job searches?

Comment: Hello David, welcome to WP. This question will probably get close votes because 'What should I do' questions are off-topic. Can you [edit it](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/35429/edit) and put in an actual proposal of how you would write in your CV? Maybe just write 'medior/senior'? We all have areas where we shine and areas where we are less proficient, this should lead to an open inquiry for a 'match' one you manage to reach the interview stage.

Comment: My request for a log-line fulfills that request.  I'll edit out the following "How to" question to leave the focus on the specific.

Comment: Just a suggestion, I work at a place that has a large amount of Mainframe COBOL programmers where we are trying to move more towards Java on distributed platforms. A few of them really want to learn Java and adopt new skills, but most are not so happy with the change. There are places like that would pay GOOD money for somebody who was modestly proficient in both to bridge the gap. Find that job and you can earn your Java experience to where you truly will be at the Senior level. These jobs do exist you just have to look for it. After that point you should be able to land any senior Java job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you market yourself: focus on what you know, and on what you have been able to deliver based on what you know - What you have been able to deliver based on what you know seems to be pretty solid stuff, by the way."... robust JUnit design, Agile development, Jenkins and nightly builds." That stuff is nice but compared to your ability to write and deliver rock solid code, this is fluff. In fact, the whole point of JUnit, Agile, etc. is to enable the delivery of rock solid code. Learn these technologies because you have to work as part of a team but the cornerstone is clearly rock solid code.

At interviews, acknowledge what you don't know and be quick and matter-of-fact about it. You have to be quick and matter-of-fact about it because every minute you spend agonizing about what you don't know is a minute that you burned off not going over what you know, what you can do, and what you can deliver. Breathe competence and easy confidence that no matter what they throw at you, you can deal with it and even toss it back :)

One more note: you may have picked up some bad habits over the last 25 years. Make sure that you know what they are if you have them, so that you can manage them going forward.

Comment: Good points. Anyone who can learn what the OP has shouldn't struggle with the others. More people eliminate themselves from agile and testing because they hate it/don't agree with it rather than not knowing it.

Comment: Hopefully, I've dropped more bad habits than I've picked up. ;)  (But I get your point.)

Comment: @DavidNeuschutz I've picked up a few bad habits of my own over the years :)

Answer (score 0):

David, seniority in a field doesn't mean you have to know everything, but you should have enough experience to know different approaches, weigh their value and decide on how to solve a problem.

Worst case call yourself a Java-Developer with 5 years of experience, this means more to an employer than the title Senior. List the ares you worked in Java, as long as you don't see anything as a no-go that you will never be able to learn, just skip the part you don't know. If you want, you can add areas you are eager to learn.